# Pageable parameter in my jpaRepository.findAll() returns an SqlSyntaxErrorException

Tags: java, oracle, jpa, repository

I'm working with JpaRepositories and I would like to combine `Specification`, `Pageable` and `Sort` parameters to my `findAll()` method.

Unfortunately I get this exception when I execute my code (I'm using an Oracle database) :

```
Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended
[...]
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet
```

Here is my service's method :

```java
public Page<Demande> findAllByAdherentWithPagination(Long idAdherent, int page, int perPage){
   Specification<Demande> spec = DemandeSpecification.hasAdherent(idAdherent);
   //page - 1 because pages starts at 0
   PageRequest pr = PageRequest.of(page - 1, perPage, sortByCreationDate());

   // -- The code stops at the following line --
   Page<Demande> demandes = repository.findAll(spec, pr);

   return demandes;
}

public Sort sortByCreationDate(){
   // "creationDate" is a property of the class Demande
   return new Sort(Sort.Direction.DESC, "creationDate");
}
```

How am I supposed to use the `PageRequest` parameter if not like this ?

The `repository` variable is a simple JpaRepository as such :

```
@Repository
public interface DemandeRepository extends ApiRepository<DemandeEntity> {
}

@NoRepositoryBean
public interface ApiRepository<E> extends JpaRepository<E, Long>, JpaSpecificationExecutor<E> {
}
```

Here is my specification method if you find it useful :

```
public static Specification<Demande> hasAdherent(Long idAdherent) {
  return (root, query, criteriaBuilder) -> {
     return criteriaBuilder.equal(root.get(Demande_.idAdherent), idAdherent);
  };
}
```

The code used to work before I add the `PageRequest` when I called the `findAll()` like this :

```java
public List<Demande> findAllByAdherentWithPagination(Long idAdherent, int page, int perPage) throws ApiException {
   Specification<Demande> spec = DemandeSpecification.hasAdherent(idAdherent);
   List<Demande> demandes = repository.findAll(spec, sortByCreationDate());

   // [...] -> Pagination "homemade" using demandes.subList(start, end)

   return demandes;
}
```

Comment: Enable SQL logging and add the generated query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I never declared in my application.properties the version of my Oracle database.

So the SQL was looking like this :

```
SELECT [...] FROM [...] WHERE [...] FECTH FIRST 10 ROWS;
```

But this syntax only appeared in Oracle 12c and my database is Oracle 10g. To fix it, I added this to the application.properties file :

```
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect
```